# postgres trouble with systemd service not starting

Tags: postgresql

we do custom installation of postgres on rhel. At present I installed 2 machines simultaeneously with Ansible (so they shoudl receive the exact same things) on rhel9 machines but fail starting postgres with systemd on some of then (not all).

**the error I am getting**

`postgresql.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_controldata: Permission denied`
but that is not relly logical given the below

```
$ ls -l /opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_controldata
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 172568 Nov 16 18:22 /opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_controldata
```

I even changed this to 777, just in case.

**my service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL 14 database server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=postgres
Group=postgres

Environment=PGHOME=/opt/db/postgres/postgresql
Environment=PGDATA=/opt/db/data/postgres/data
Environment=PGPORT=5432

ExecStartPre=/opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_controldata ${PGDATA}
ExecStart=/opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o "-p ${PGPORT}" -w -t 300
ExecReload=/opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl reload -D ${PGDATA} -s
ExecStop=/opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl stop -D ${PGDATA} -s -m fast

# Disable OOM kill on the postmaster
OOMScoreAdjust=-1000
# Don't kill Postgres when doing a longer recovery
TimeoutSec=3600

# Set Limits here (see /etc/security/limits.d/30-postgres.conf)
LimitNOFILE=16384
LimitNPROC=65536
LimitMEMLOCK=2097152

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

postgres itself works and can be started/stoppped with `pg_ctl ...` without any issue

any idea, how this could be fixed?

Comment: Why do you have this ExecStartPre? I'm not sure what the pg_controldata call might be useful for here.

Comment: I was wondering the same. Colleague wrote that file. might need to inquire about that. What I trie dis to comment that line out, whihc leads to the same kinf og error (`permission denied on /opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl`)  on the following `ExecStart` line *which also does not really seeem to make sense to me.

Comment: What does the '.' mean at the end of the permissions block?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the command manually as user `postgres`:

```bash
/opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_controldata -D /opt/db/data/postgres/data
```

You should encounter the same error. Look at the permissions of both the executable and the data directory. Then look at the permissions of all the containing directories. Something should be missing there.

The command is pretty useless to run before starting the server.

The permissions on `/opt/db/postgres/postgresql/bin/pg_controldata` are dangerous. Anybody could write over the executable.